# How to set date formate for UIDatePicker View

Tags: ios, objective-c, locale, uidatepicker

How to set date formate to the UIDatePickerView for month MMM using locale can we achieve it?

Is there away to set three char of month to UIDatePickerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't set a specific format on a date picker. You can set the locale (which defaults to the user's current locale) which affects the format.

If you truly want a date picker with a specific format (bad idea because it will likely confuse users), you will need to create your custom date picker using `UIPickerView`.